# Does BASH's ability to handle numbers scale with processor bitwidth?

Tags: bash

I recently had to write a library for BASH to handle large numbers because I had to glue some software outputs together that needed basic arithmetic.  If I was writing a shell, I would not assume that most people would need 4096-bit arithmetic.  However, I have two machines that both can handle up to 64-bit arithmetic in BASH, but my question is how this is related to CPUs.

On a 32-bit processor, is BASH's maximum arithmetic capability 32-bits, and on a 16-bit processor or 8-bit processor with a some OS and BASH would the maximum numerical capability be 16-bits and 8-bits respectively?

The BASH manual did not shed any light onto what the limits would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash's internal arithmetic is the bitwidth of the *target* for which bash was compiled, which may be less than the bitwidth of the *processor* on which it's running.  Specifically, bash's internal arithmetic is `intmax_t` per [this bug-report comment](http://savannah.gnu.org/support/?108381#comment2).  The `intmax_t` type is

> a signed integer type capable of representing any value of any signed integer type

per [the docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html), and is defined by the compiler.  Therefore, bash arithmetic is limited by the compilation environment.  Even on a 64-bit processor, a bash version compiled for a 32-bit target will be limited to 32 bits.

Details: in [expr.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/expr.c#n22), the source says

> All arithmetic is done as intmax_t integers with no checking for overflow (though division by 0 is caught and flagged as an error).

**Edit** Here's a runtime test for bit width that (I think) only relies on bash being signed two's complement.  Works on my system - YMMV.

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=1; $i>0; i*=2)); do : ; done    
    # Set the highest-order bit, which is a negative number in signed math.
echo "$(echo "l(-($i))/l(2)"|bc -l)/1+1" | bc
    # Output the position of that bit
```

The inner `bc -l` computes `log2(|$i|)`, the index of the highest-order bit plus just a little bit since the two's complement range is asymmetric around zero.  The outer `bc` computes the ceiling of that value.  (`bc` when run without `-l` truncates divisions - thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168486/63804)).  On my system, this outputs `64`.

Empirical test:

```
~$ uname -a                      ---  NOTE: 64-bit Cygwin vvvvvv
CYGWIN_NT-6.3 localhost 2.5.2(0.297/5/3) 2016-06-23 14:29 x86_64 Cygwin
~$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.46(6)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
   <cut>       --- NOTE: 64-bit bash ^^^^^^
~$ echo $(( 2 ** 32 ))
4294967296                    <--- so >32 bit
~$ echo $(( 2 ** 64 ))
0                             <--- oops - bigger than 64 bit doesn't work
~$ echo $(( 2 ** 63 ))
-9223372036854775808          <--- but 64 bit does (and is signed)
```

Comment: ... but note that none of this is documented in Bash's *user* documentation.  In principle, therefore, it might change without warning in some future version of Bash.  The only thing [the user docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic) actually have to say on the topic is "[Arithmetic] Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error."

Comment: No need for bc, or complex log math (just count): `j=1; i=1;while ((i<<=1)); do ((j++)) ; done; echo "$j"` (a shift `<<` is faster than a multiply `*`).